# No map received on RVIZ2

Tags: ros2, rviz, slam, ros-humble, nav2

i did slam cartographer and saved succesfully the map. But after running nav2 the map doess not appear on RVIZ2 and the message says no map received. I did check and /scan and /map works, also map_server running. What could be the problem?

Comment: You'll need to provide more information / logs. Also make sure to read the docs for the map server on navigation.ros.org's configuration guides to see if potentially you're not setting it up correctly for the type of data that cartographer provides